# Use .toFixed() to only show 3 decimal when required

Tags: javascript

How can I use .toFixed() to this result.

```
number     display
------     -------
1          1
1.23       1.23
1.23456    1.235
```

I have been using .toFixed(3). But it's display.

```
number     display
------     -------
1          1.000
1.23       1.230
1.23456    1.235
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
Math.round(yournum * 1000) / 1000
```

or you can try:

```
+(Math.round(num + "e+3")  + "e-3")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove unwanted zeroes or the dot.

```js
console.log([1, 1.23, 1.23456].map(v => v.toFixed(3).replace(/\.?0+$/, '')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) instead of `toFixed`

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumSignificantDigits: 4}).format(1 ));
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumSignificantDigits: 4}).format(1.23 ));
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumSignificantDigits: 4}).format(1.23456 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple function to check for the number of decimal places and then only run `toFixed` if it reaches 3.

Something like this would work.

Here's a snippet

```js
let dP = n => {
  if (n.toString().includes('.')) return n.toString().split('.')[1].length
};

[1, 1.23, 1.23456].forEach(n => {
  console.log(dP(n) >= 3 ? n.toFixed(3) : n)
})
```

I hope this helps